# Is it possible to run MongoDB javascript scripts in DBeaver

Tags: mongodb, dbeaver

[DBeaver's wiki](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/wiki/NoSQL-MongoDB) shows a simple query against a Mongo database but what about admin scripts?  It would be great to develop these in DBeaver but I've tried a few permutations to no avail.

Here's an example of a maintenance script:

```
var cursor = db.album.find({}, {"k": 1 })
var albumKeys = []

while( cursor.hasNext() ){
    albumKeys.push( cursor.next()['k']);
}

cursor = db.song.find({ "alb" : { $not : { $in : albumKeys } } } )
var songsWithMissingAlbum = []

while( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    songsWithMissingAlbum.push(cursor.next())
}

printjson(songsWithMissingAlbum)
```

Comment: What permutations have you tried and what is the error message or output? Also, what specific versions of MongoDB server and DBeaver are you using? Does this query work as expected in the `mongo` shell? One likely problem is the second assignment of `cursor` without declaring it as a new `var`; the `mongo` shell will automatically iterate this statement so your first 20 results will be printed in the shell and consumed before your `cursor.hasNext()` loop below. See: [Iterate a Cursor in the `mongo` Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/).

Comment: Good point.  DBeaver: EE 4.0.5, Mongo 2.6.x - Mostly had fails like: `com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16722: 'exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' on server 127.0.0.1:22164. The full response is { "errmsg" : "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", "code" : 16722, "ok" : 0.0 }` as dialog messages. Yes, this scripts works as: `mongo <mydb> myscript.js`

Comment: Having expected it work, I tried a few approaches.  But gave up until somebody might clarify if it's expected to work :)

Comment: I increased log level to see what DBeaver is sending to the MongoDB server. It is using the [`eval` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/eval/) which has been deprecated since MongoDB 3.0 and has significant performance and security caveats. This is definitely not equivalent to running similar admin scripts in the `mongo` shell and I wouldn't recommend this approach (especially accessing any non-development environments). I'd also note that MongoDB 2.6 reached end of life in October, 2016 so you should ideally upgrade to an actively maintained server version.

Comment: Interesting about the eval(). It's a shame as working on admin scripts is much easier in the IDE rather than vi on the remote server.  Yes, I'm aware of the server version legacy of course. Thanks again.

Comment: If you prefer a GUI there are other admin UIs that provide client-side scripting for MongoDB. A search for "shell-centric MongoDB GUI" should turn up some likely suspects such as Robomongo and MongoBooster, and there are other UIs that wrap the `mongo` shell. The [MongoDB Tools](http://mongodb-tools.com/) site has a non-exhaustive list that might be a be a helpful starting point.

Answer (score 0):

subtle differences to the script allows this to run in DBeaver, and (with a small adaptation) as a script for `mongo <script.js>`

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDB");

cursor = db.album.find({}, {'k': 1 });

albumKeys = [];

while( cursor.hasNext() ){
    albumKeys.push( cursor.next()['k']);
}




cursor = db.song.find({ 'alb' : { $not : { $in : albumKeys } } } );
songsWithMissingAlbum = [];

while( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    songsWithMissingAlbum.push(cursor.next());
}


return songsWithMissingAlbum; /* printjson(songsWithMissingAlbum) */
```

**Pertinent changes**

1. semicolon line terminations
2. final `return` statement (for dbeaver) which must be changed to `printjson(..)` call in command line script for `mongo`.
3. added db and connection setup which works in both.